# Linux command to identify the USB connected to a server

Tags: linux, usb, usb-flash-drive, mount

Imagine you have two identical USB-stick connected to your server.
You are connected with ssh.
When you type `lsusb` you can see the two USB drives.

My question is:
If you want mount this stick

```
"Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0951:1624 Kingston Technology DataTraveler G2 4GB Pen Drive"
```

how can you know if this USB-stick is sda or sdb etc...

OR more precisely what command should I use to identify the correct USB (hardware)

Comment: Look in /dev/disk/by-id if you are running Debian.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the order the sticks were plugged in you could use `dmesg` to see which USB device was mapped to /dev/sd*, they should show up there in the same order they were plugged in.

Also, if you could try `udevadm info -q path -n /dev/sdb` and iterate over the possible devices to see which has the USB connection info matching the stick you want.